# Cannot send email use looping with error response code 550 5.7.0

Tags: php, arrays, email, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send multiple email recipients inside loop, but this email only sends some emails and stops with the error:

`Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 354 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.0 Requested action not taken: too many emails per second.."`

this is my controller:

```
        try{
          foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose('notification_new_invitation', [
              'title' => $data->title,
              'description' => $data->description,
              'startdate' => date_format(date_create($data->startdate), 'd M Y'),
              'starttime' => date_format(date_create($data->startdate), 'H:i')
            ])
              ->setFrom('noreply@test.com')
              ->setTo(trim($value['email']))
              ->setSubject('Invitation Letter')
              ->send();
          }
          
          // $status = '1';
        } catch(\Swift_TransportException $e){
          echo $e;
          $status = '0';
        }
```

is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: You would need to check with the service you use to send e-mails, they are limiting the amount you can send in one go.  You could add a pause between e-mails or after a certain number sent.

Comment: @NigelRen how to add a pause between emails? btw i'm using mailtrap here, does this have any effect?

Comment: Check https://mailtrap.io/pricing?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6vbW_8X28wIVQZ7tCh3SSwgJEAAYASABEgLxXvD_BwE

Comment: Mailtrap limits you to 10 emails per second. Solution: send one email. Sleep for 100ms. Then send the next email. **usleep(100000);**  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php Read this article: https://www.dorelljames.com/blog/solving-mailtraps-error-550-too-many-emails-per-second/

Answer (score 0):

I think you neet to increase max message value in your SMTP configuration:

```
maxMessages: 3, // send 3 emails per second
```

Comment: where i can set this? i can't find any function to set maxmessages in mailer component